# Prove that the 4 degree polynomial has at least two roots

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, polynomials

In my assignment I have to prove that:

> Let $P(x)=x^4+a_{3}x^3+a_{2}x^2+a_{1}x+a_{0}$.
>
> Prove that if P has a root in $x_{0}$ and $P'(x_{0})\ne0$ then P has a least two roots.

My solution has a problem in it, and I wondered if you can help me with it.

Since the functoin is a polynomial then it is differentiable always. If we calculate the limit:

$$\lim _{x\to \infty}P(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}P(x)=\infty$$

I  tried to solve is by showing through Rolle's theorem by contradiction that the derivative is always $\ne0$ but no one told me that $a_{i}\ne0$ so I'm stuck.

I know I should you IVT but I'm pretty much stuck.

Your help is appriciated.